# Excel currency shortcut produces € symbol

Tags: excel, windows-xp, excel-2003

The Excel shortcut of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> is supposed to convert selected cells into the currency format. However, mine prompts me that "Data on the Clipboard is not the same size and shape as the selected area. Do you want to paste the data anyway?" and if i click OK, it replaces the contents of the first selected cell with a € symbol. If only one cell is selected when I perform the keystroke, that cell's contents are replaced without the prompt.

I've tried to reset my regional settings and formats but nothing has worked. Googling only produced one legitimate question which was responded with a troll answer. I'm hoping someone here might have experienced (and fixed) this before.

This is on Windows XP and Office 2003 with no add-ins.

Comment: Can you provide some of your data? I just tried it with self created values and it worked fine. I also find the prompt disturbing, as it shouldn't have to do anything with the conversion of formats and is normally thrown when you try to wrongfully insert data...

Comment: Does this happen on every workbook/worksheet? Does it happen if you try immediately on a reboot with nothing else running?

Comment: @daZza the data doesn't matter. it does this even with a new worksheet where i input some random number and hit that key combination.

Comment: @Raystafarian: yes, all the time.

Comment: Is Ctrl+Shft+4 assigned to some other command in error? The message suggests a clipboard paste operation is taking place. The error indicates the data in the clipboard has a different shape to the selected region.

Comment: @Pekka: does excel have a built-in override somewhere? there are definitely no external apps doing that as this is my work machine.

Comment: @tys yes, you can use VBA to change the [.onkey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197461.aspx) properties of keystrokes. Is there any code running in excel? on startup? in the personal macro wb?

Comment: there isn't a personal macro running. i've tried removing all com add-ins etc. looks like no one has really experienced this strange behaviour.

Comment: Have you checked to see if it happens in excel- safe mode? Or even windows safe mode?

Comment: i don't think excel 2003 has safe mode, so no.

Comment: This actually sounds like it is preserving the source formatting and/or is getting some screwy result from XML/HTML you might not know you are copying with the content.  Does this happen if you paste the content into Notepad, then copy from notepad back over to Excel?

Comment: @tys what is the default language of your windows version, there was a bug in excel 2003 when changing regional setting would not change the defaults in excel but only adds the new settings to excel (It's been many years since i last used it though, and i don't have a copy anymore).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no solution to this question and I gave up trying after a few months. Removed my Office 2003 install and replaced it with Office 2010 instead, which fixed the problem. Appears there were no background processes involved, probably just a faulty Office/Excel install.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably some programs running, or macros imported in your office program, that use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>. A few possible solutions:

Enable the developer tab `(File > Options > Customize Ribbon > in the right hand box there should be an unchecked box named Developer > check it on > click OK.)` Afterwards, check your macros. IF there are any, they could be causing the problems.

Or you could also try to change your shortcut to something else. Go to `Excel Options> Customize> Keyboard shortcuts Customize.` Then find the applicable command and change it to something else.

Answer (score 1):

What is the number format in the workbook's Currency Style (Format|Style)?

More recent versions of Excel with the ribbon bar have this under the "number" drop down on the Home ribbon

Make sure the Symbol is listed as $

Comment: It is $, and changing that setting does not get rid of the behaviour. Excel should simply change the number format of all selected cells to the currency format. I'm hoping someone has experienced this before, else I will have to do an overhaul of the office suite.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that it is the shift is the key being sent,  the result you describe it what happens with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>

Comment: absolutely. what are you suggesting?

Comment: try the onscreen keyboard to confirm

Comment: i get the same result. urgh.